# UrlRewriteFilter with Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I'd like to setup an automatic redirect from `https://1.2.3.4/` to `https://1.2.3.4/myapp` with Tomcat 7, in order to setup the **myapp** deployment into the root directory.

I'm reading about **[UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/)**, but I've just noticed that `webapp/ROOT/WEB-INF` is empty.

Accoring to the documentation, which is the proper way to setup that as desired?

Answer (score 0):

It's okay if `ROOT/WEB-INF` is empty: just create a new `web.xml` file with only your `url-rewrite` configuration in there. If you are going to redirect everything, your `ROOT` context only needs to have `WEB-INF/lib/url-rewrite.jar` and `WEB-INF/web.xml` and nothing else.